# Get list of all reachable servers regardless of Zone with Ribbon load balancer

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul, netflix-ribbon

We are having 4 zones, each zone having a zuul and UI service running. Ribbon is our load balancer across services.

We are achieving sticky session in Zuul with a custom load balancing rule as specified in

https://github.com/alejandro-du/vaadin-microservices-demo/blob/master/proxy-server/src/main/java/com/example/StickySessionRule.java

As you can see in the above file, there is line which gets the list of reachable servers for a particular service

```
List<Server> servers = getLoadBalancer().getReachableServers();
```

The servers list will have only one server because of Zone affinity being enabled.

Is there any way to get all the available servers without taking zone into consideration?

We are looking for something which could replace the above mentioned load balancer call.

In the current stickysession rule, we are using ZoneAvoidanceRule. We also tried AvailabilityFilteringRule, BaseLoadBalancer & RoundRobinRule. But none of them are giving all 4 server instance reference.

What can done to read all the server list?

Answer (score 0):

Finally was about to achieve this.

All I had to do was remove the line

```
List<Server> servers = getLoadBalancer().getReachableServers();
```

and then inject the EurekaClient bean which has info on all application instances and then read the servers list as

```
Application app = eurekaClient.getApplication("application-name");
List<InstanceInfo> allinstances = app.getInstances();
```